# C++: Implementing insert function for a linked list, prev_ptr ends up being NULL

Tags: c++

**node.h:**

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <iostream>
namespace mdm{
    class node{
    public:
        typedef int value_type;
        node(const value_type& init_data = value_type(), node *init_link = NULL){
            data = init_data;
            link = init_link;
        }

        void setData(const value_type& newData){
            data = newData;
        }
        void setLink(node *newLink){
            link = newLink;
        }
        value_type getdata() const {
            return data;
        }

        const node *linker() const {
            return link;
        }
        node *linker(){
            return link;
        }



    private:
        value_type data;
        node *link;

    };
}

#endif // !node_h
```

**linked_list.h:**

```
#ifndef linked_list_h
#define linked_list_h
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
namespace mdislamwork_at_gmail_com{
    class llist{
    public:
        llist(node *head = NULL){
            head_ptr = head;
        }

        size_t list_length(const node *head_ptr);
        void insert(const node::value_type& entry, size_t position);
        void remove(node del);
        void insert_to_head(node *&head_ptr, const node::value_type &entry);


    private:
        node *head_ptr;

    };
}
#endif // !linked_list.h
```

**linked_list.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;


namespace mdm{
    size_t llist::list_length(const node *head_ptr){
        const node *cursor;
        size_t count = 0;
        for (cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->linker()) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }


    void llist::insert(const node::value_type& entry, size_t position){

        node* prev_ptr = head_ptr;
        if (list_length(head_ptr) == 0)
            insert_to_head(head_ptr, entry);
        else{
            assert(prev_ptr != NULL);
            size_t count = 0;
            while (count < position){
                prev_ptr = prev_ptr->linker();
                count++;
            }
        }
        node *m_head_ptr;
        assert(prev_ptr != NULL);
        m_head_ptr = prev_ptr->linker();
        insert_to_head(m_head_ptr, entry);
        prev_ptr->setLink(m_head_ptr);



    }

    void llist::remove(node del){

    }

    void llist::insert_to_head(node *&head_ptr, const node::value_type &entry){
        head_ptr = new node(entry, head_ptr);
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
#include "linked_list.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace mdm;

int main() {
    node *head_ptr = NULL;
    llist linked_list(head_ptr);
    linked_list.insert_to_head(head_ptr, 44);
    cout << linked_list.list_length(head_ptr) << endl;
    linked_list.insert_to_head(head_ptr, 49);
    cout << linked_list.list_length(head_ptr) << endl;
    linked_list.insert(5,2);
    //linked_list.insert(5, 2);
    cout << linked_list.list_length(head_ptr) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I posted the entirety of the code. I am having trouble inserting at an n-th position. For some reason in the insert implementation, the prev_ptr is NULL when it should have the memory address of where the new node will be placed.

Comment: Give us a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the problem. Your while loop might terminate one element too late, but your code snippet does not contain how you call the function when the error occurs and is also missing some other definitions, so it's hard to tell. One thing that looks fishy: You never check in your while loop whether `linker()` actually returns a valid pointer for the next element. So, if a too large `position` value is passed to the function, you might run into a segmentation fault (or the problem you described, if it's just off by 1).

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what the problem is what with head_ptr and its operations out of the scope of your posted method. What is head_ptr? A node*? a node? How are your nodes inserted initially? The scope of this method in relation to your problem is hard to understand.

Check to see if the head_ptr variable is null throughout the whole of your program. Is it always null? Does it become null? What other operations for your linked list have you implemented? Do they work ok? Its just really hard to tell what is wrong when you provide one method to an entire implementation.

Comment: Added the rest. head_ptr is a node* which points to the first node in the linked list. The assert function tells me that only when the while-loop ends does the prev_ptr become NULL. As Oguk mentioned, I may be finishing the loop one element too late.